# Saving an image after using range display

Tags: matlab

I am using kmeans clustering to segment an image. My function returns values between 1-3 with the same size as the input image, then I am using imshow(L, []); to display the image but I cannot find a way which would save the image exactly the same as displayed on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mat2gray`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mat2gray.html) to map the values in your matrix L to values between 0 (black) and 1 (white), similar as what `imshow(L, [])` does. Then use `imwrite` to save the image.

```
L = 1 + (3-1).*rand(500); % 500-by-500 image with values between 1 and 3

figure(1); clf;
imshow(L, [])

Img = mat2gray(L);
figure(2); clf;
imshow(Img)

imwrite(Img, 'yourimage.png')
```